# Inflectional affixes that modify nouns (Possessive form)

Tags: suffixes

I've been reading about affixes (suffixes in particular currently) and I figured that the ('s) or the (s') that comes at the end of some nouns counts (indicating either the possession or plural form) as a suffix. Now since I only saw this in one particular site I wanted to make sure it's true and if it's true some examples would be like:

Thomas' (OR Thomas's), John's, The girls', The men's, Hers, His, Its?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. What do you want to know is true?  If it's a suffix?  I think linguists generally call it a clitic, which is a special kind of affix.

Comment: Yes: the genitive marker, ' is a suffix. Note that "hers" "his" etc, are genitive personal pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple rules to form a possessive:

Singular nouns, including names, including words ending in "s"  **Rule** "Add apostrophe-s":

cat -> cat's /  John -> John's / address -> address's  / James -> James's

Plural nouns ending in "s"  **Rule** "add an apostrophe":

cats -> cats' / addresses -> addresses'

Irregular plural nouns **Rule** "add apostrophe-s"

men -> men's   / geese  -> geese's

Pronouns **Rule** "These have special forms and never use an apostrophe"

Me -> My -> Mine
You -> Your -> Yours
Him -> His -> His
Her -> Her -> Hers
It -> Its -> Its
Them -> Their -> Theirs

Comment: It is worth noting that some people prefer  James'  to James's    And both spellings get used.

Comment: Some classical names and biblical names that end with s are generally written with s'.  Such as Socrates', Jesus', Moses'.  I would also include James and Thomas in that group, since they are biblical names.

Comment: I believe the question is whether 's is considered an affix, rather than the spelling rules.

Answer (score 0):

's or s' isn't an affix, but a [*clitic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic).

It denotes possession, not plural form.

Among your examples, only these have the clitic: *Thomas', Thomas's, John's, The girls', The men's*

Of the others, *"his"* and "*its*", are whole words without individual parts. It's clear that their form historically comes from the addition of 's to "he" and "it", but in modern English, they are whole words, not roots with a suffix.

The word "hers" is a pronoun, and doesn't have the function of possessive adjective like all the other words. The feminine equivalent is "her", which doesn't show the possessive 's at all.

Comment: I'd say that the '_s_ (or _s_') is a suffix, not a clitic, so "doctor's" in "the doctor's house", for example, has genitive case-inflection. A clitic, by contrast, is a separate syntactic word that merges phonologically with the preceding word, as '_m_ is a clitic that merges with "I" in "I'm ill".

Answer (score 0):

For most English words, we add "s" to make it plural. Like "one dog, two dogs".

Add "'s" to make it possessive. "The dog's bone". A bone belonging to one dog.

Add "s'" to make it plural and possessive. "The dogs' bones". Bones belonging to many dogs.

There are exceptions to this. For example the plural of "man" is NOT "mans" but "men". The plural of "child" is "children". Etc. These special cases are another whole subject.

We still use "'s" for possession. "The child's toy". When there's a non-standard plural, we use "'s" for possession on the plural. "The children's toys".

Whether this is properly called a "suffix" ... one could quibble about definitions. But it's something we tack on to the end of a word.